# Existe alguma forma de executar um evento sempre que o método SqlConnection.Update de Dapper.Contrib.Extensions é executado numa entidade?

Tags: dapper

Eu estou usando Dapper a pouco tempo e por isso tenho pouca experiência com o mesmo. Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de detectar mudanças em um campo específico.

Preciso disso porque em um determinada tabela, toda vez que um campo for atualizado, preciso atualizar outro campo, concatenando com ".JPG".

Por exemplo

```
using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;

// ...

var remessa = conn.Get<Remessa>(1);

remessa.Campo1 = "5000";

// remessa.Campo2 = remessa.Campo1 + ".jpg";

conn.Update(remessa);
```

No exemplo acima, preciso que a linha comentada referente ao `Campo2` seja executada automaticamente, toda vez que eu executar o `SqlConnection.Update` (isto é, não quero ficar repetindo esse trecho na minha aplicação). Tem como fazer isso com Dapper?

Comment: Esse campo/propriedade não deveria ser, então, "calculado"? Você realmente precisa desse campo "real" se o valor dele na verdade é sempre dependente do valor do outro? Eu acredito que na definição de 'remessa', declará-lo como `public string Campo2 { get { return Campo1 + ".jpg"; } }` seria suficiente. Ele nem precisa existir no banco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `Dapper` não tem esse recurso para fazer essa mudança, então, faça diretamente na propriedade da classe, todas as vezes que alterar a propriedade `Campo1` pelo código também é alterado `Campo2`, ***exemplo***:

```cs
public class Exemplo 
{
    private string _campo1;
    public string Campo1 
    {
        get 
        {
            return _campo1;
        }
        set 
        {
            _campo1 = value;
            Campo2 = value + ".JPG"; // mudança a partir do Campo1 para Campo2
        }
    }
    public string Campo2 { get; set; }
}
```

na sua utilização:

```cs
Exemplo ex = new Exemplo { Campo1 = "0001" };
System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Campo2);
```

Assim é o correto, já visto que o `Dapper` para alterar os campos precisa que suas propriedades tenha sido modificadas. Esse é o primeiro exemplo, na propriedade `Campo2`, talvez não precise ter o `set;`, porque, a mesma é um dado gerado por outra propriedade (`calculado`) exemplo:

```cs
public string Campo2 { get; private set; }
```

[Exemplo OnLine Ideone](https://ideone.com/RjPUCX)